# kafka Offset commit failing org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have written a kafka consumer using spring-kafka library (spring-boot-starter-parent 2.3.4.RELEASE).
I have following consumer configuration in my code

```
 /**
     * configuration for kafka consumers at container level
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(1);     factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * default kafka consumer factory
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    /**
     * configuration for kafka consumer at thread level.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, localhost:9092);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return props;
    }
```

Following is my listener method :

```
@KafkaListener(id = "client", topics = "MyTopic", clientIdPrefix = "client")
    public void listen(@Payload UserNotification data,Acknowledgment ack) {

        // Business logic

        ack.acknowledge();
    }
```

Here I am reading 1 message at a time, apply business logic and use  ack.acknowledge() to commit offset, but what I have seen, sometime offset commit succeed but many time I get org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException on line ack.acknowledge(). **Here I can confirm that business logic is completed in 2 sec max.** Following is the detailed exception:

```
2022-06-03|04:27:04.326|INSTANCEID_IS_UNDEFINED|xyz-856495f857-8nqx7|client-0-C-1|ERROR||||o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer|149|Error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.xyz.listen(java.lang.String,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment)' threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:157)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:113)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeErrorHandler(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2012)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1911)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1838)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1735)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1465)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1128)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Can someone please help me why this is happening, because default poll interval is 5 min and group coordinator should not kickout the consumer if processing just takes 2 sec.

Comment: It still reads: "Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group."

Comment: @MartinZeitler thats true , but why its getting kicked out?

Comment: Try `bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh` ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must be able to process `max.poll.records` (default 500) in `max.poll.interval.ms` (default 300000 - 5 mins).

If it takes 2 seconds per record, it will take up to 16.6667 minutes to process the batch, and you will be kicked out of the group.

Reduce `max.poll.records` and/or increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: If you see in the above code , I am not doing any batch processing. Is there any configuration in my code which sets the consumer for batch processing. If there is no processing then after processing a single record , I call ack.acknowledge() which should commit the offset after 2 sec.

Comment: The container is fetching a batch (`max.poll.records`) and sending them to the listener one-at-a-time. You **must** reduce this to something much smaller. e.g. `props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 50);`